# Angular 2: Two select Boxex "Exchange" Data

Tags: javascript, angular

I´d like to build 2 select fields. in the first I want to display all my members (objects in my database):

```
<select multiple size="15" name="members" id="members">
   <option *ngFor="let member of members" [value]="member.$key">
     {{member.lastName}} {{member.firstName}}
   </option>
</select>
```

In the second I want to display all members of the current team (selected from url param id)

```
<select size="15" name="assignedMembers" id="assignedMembers">
    <option *ngFor="let assignedPlayer of team.assignedPlayers"[value]="assignedPlayer.$key">
      {{assignedPlayer.lastName}} {{assignedPlayer.firstName}}
    </option>
 </select>`
```

How can I change now the values from the first to the second list and vice versa to be able to save the assignedMembers later?